# Selections are slow when selecting on a range of numbers

Tags: sql, performance, select

I have a GeoIP location database with my IP block table having a starting and ending column with is the range of IP addresses that is applicable to the respective location record (i.e. city, state, etc).  The block table has about 5.4 million rows of data.  When I search on a particular IP address (Example below), the search query is very slow.  Is there a better way to redesign the select statement or table to improve the performance?

```
SELECT [locationID] FROM [GeoLocationView] where (GeoLocationView.startipNum <= ip) and     (GeoLocationView.endipnum) >= ip)
```

The table looks like the following

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GeoCity_Blocks](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[startIpNum] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[endIpNum] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[locId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GeoCity_Blocks_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[startIpNum] ASC,
[endIpNum] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What does your execution plan look like?

Comment: Are there any indexes on your table?

Comment: You give us the definition of a table, but you appear to be selecting from a view.  What does the view definition look like?  Are all selects from this view slow, or just this one?

Comment: [What] [is] [the] [meaning] [of] [all] [these] [brackets] [in] [the] [code][?] [IMHO] [it] [has] [nothing] [to] [do] [with] [SQL][,] [and] [makes] [it] [very] [hard] [to] [read].

Answer (score 1):

I would very much recommend adding an index on startIpNum and endIpNum.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was doing an index scan and not an index seek.  Changing the select statement from "inner join" to "inner loop join" worked nicely for this call.

I had indexes on the startIPNum and EndIPNum columns, but it was the index scan that was killing the performance.  I played around with clustered vs non-clustered indexes and did not see real any performance differences.